# install OPENCV to Rasbian( Debian Linux )

Tags: linux, debian, windows, raspbian, opencv

[image]

I installed rasbian(debian) for windows . 
I want to install OPENCV.
I have write the newest link .

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip
```

But I got error in this picture.
What can I do now ?

Comment: Run a `df -h` on the machine. I'm pretty sure you don't have enough space on your raspberry pi...

Comment: Thank you ryekayo .

I use windows7 . I havent raspberrypi now . I install rasbian(debian linux) to windows7.because ı want to exercise . ı wrote df -h .I saw , 1.8gb was full . OK , What can I increasing ??

Comment: Raspberry Pi's may have additional storage devices like an SD card readers or something to that nature. It really depends on the type of device you bought. I would check with the user's manual to see if it has any type of secondary storage features like a USB card slot or a SD card reader

Comment: My computer have 1048Gb . So ı have lots of storage. But 1.8gb for rasbian ( debian ) . what can ı increasing storage in my computer for debian linux ? 

you can this image. 
http://i.hizliresim.com/DkVYol.png

Comment: Furkan, your device that your running Debian off of is filled to the max. Your PC may have 1048 GB but the device running Debian does not. From what I see on your screen, the device you are using is raspberry pi, and you need to consult with the owner's manual to check if there is a way to expand your storage via USB or SD.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comment, running a:

```
df -h
```

will tell you how much storage is available. According to what you told me, your storage is full. I therefore recommended in my other comment to check the Owner's Manual for secondary storage feature(s) such as an SD card slot or USB slot. That is probably the only way you can expand the storage.